# Moderate growth functions on complex algebraic varieties.

Tags: reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Does anybody know a reference that discusses  moderate growth (continuous or measurable) functions on complex algebraic varieties?

I'm interested in such a discussion in the generality of varieties that are not necessarily smooth or affine.
I'm especially interested in the behavior of such functions w.r.t. proper maps.

Comment: I learnt about moderate growth from Deligne's book on differential equations. But I am not sure if the singular case is treated there.